# How to loop an array of an array?

Tags: angularjs

Suppose I have such json string:

```
{ "subData" : [ ["a", "b", "c" , "d"] ] }
```

I am not able to loop thru the data in the array by using this:

```
<tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="temp in subData">
       <td ng-repeat="value in temp">
          {{value}}
       </td>
   </tr> 
</tbody>
```

Did I miss anything?

Thanks

Comment: A *json string* you say...post the full object containing `subData`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The json object is very simple. I update the json example.

Comment: make sure the data is assigned correctly to the scope i.e. if $scope.data is $scope.data = { "subData" : [ ["a", "b", "c" , "d"] ] }; Than you'd need to ng-repeat="temp in data.subData"

Comment: @imguru suggest you paste OP object into jsonlint.com and will find it is valid

Comment: @imguru: Do you mean I need to have a key-pair value in order to use ng-repeat?

Comment: @Kintarō  no, you can certainly have an array of strings if that suits your model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you put your data into `$scope` properly?

Also, I suggest you to use `track by $index` when you lopping arrays, to avoid data duplication problem

JS:

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.subData = [ ["a", "b", "c" , "a"], ["a", "a", "c" , "c"] ];
    });
```

HTML:

```
<table ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="temp in subData">
           <td ng-repeat="value in temp track by $index">
              {{value}}
           </td>
       </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Xc8r/)

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, do you have an actual table element wrapping that tbody?

```
<table>
   <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="temp in subData">
       <td ng-repeat="value in temp">{{value}}</td>
     </tr> 
   </tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/86qsD/

Answer (score -1):

Yes you miss table tag 
http://jsbin.com/wozido/1/edit

```
 <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="temp in subData track by $index">
          <td ng-repeat="i in temp track by $index">
            {{i}}
          </td>
        </tr>  
 </tbody>
```

Comment: How's this different?

Comment: <table> tag was missed

Comment: It's probably pretty safe to assume the `table` tag is there - the problem seems to be that `subData` isn't the `$scope` variable name.

Comment: Strange enough...if my array has duplicate value, ng-repeat is not rendering { "subData" : [ ["a", "a", "c" , "d"] ] }

Comment: please add  track by $index  ie:"value in temp track by $index"